# Django: How to create forms for each element on the page?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have model of Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

On one page I get all Post objects. And for each Post object, I want to get form to edit this Post on this page.

For that, I created PostEditForm with hidden field "post_id" to identify editing post

```
class PostEditForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
   post_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

I don't know how to get this form on page so that post_id has been written in a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you approach is simpliest. Better to create one form, which will be used primarily as validator:

```
class PostEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Post
```

Then you need to pass data from your fields with AJAX, and validate it with created form:

```
var form = $('.form'); // Your forms selector
form.on('submit', function(e){
    var self = $(this),
        post_id = self.attr('data-post-id');

    $.ajax({
      url: "/some-backend-url/",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
         post_id: post_id,
         text: $('input.text', self).val(),
         title: $('input.title', self).val(),
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
      // Some callback here.
    });
});
```

And update your post with your backend:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax():
        post = models.Post.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('post_id')
        form = PostEditForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            # return json response
    return HttpResponseBadRequest
```

You can do same thing with class-based `UpdateView` too.

Comment: Thank you! Very good idea to write "post_id" in attr 'data-post-id'

Answer (score 0):

Django provides [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for this specific purpose.

```
class PostEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def some_view(request,some_pk):
    post = models.Post.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
    if request.POST:
        form = PostEditForm(request.POST,instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do more if you like
            form.save()
    else:
        form = PostEditForm(instance=post)

    #return response
```

You can render hidden form fields in a template (`{% for field in form.hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endif %}`), but with this approach you shouldn't need to.